Recreate Gitlab CI before_script / extends functionality to avoid duplicate code
With Gitlab CI, you can use before_script to run a script before every script command of a yaml file (cf. example 1 below).
A similar functionality can be achieved with extends and a hidden job, making it possible to also reuse other parameters (e.g. image, cf. example 2).
In this way, duplicate code can be avoided by defining content once and referencing it multiple times in different sections of the yaml file.
How can this be replicated with Azure Pipelines yaml files?
There seems to be no equivalent of before_script and  extends does not feature the Gitlab CI yaml functionality.
Gitlab CI yaml file, example 1:
before_script:
    - echo "this runs before every script command"

stages:
    - test

test-code:
    stage: test
    # before_script will be run before this script command
    script:
        - echo "run script"

Gitlab CI yaml file, example 2:
.hidden_job
    image: python:3.12-bookworm
    - script:
        - echo "reference this to avoid duplicate yaml code"

stages:
    - test

test-code:
    stage: test
    extends: .hidden_job
    script:
        - echo "run script"


I'm afraid there is no equivalent features in Azure DevOps as before_script and extends feature in Gitlab CI.

duplicate code can be avoided by defining content once and referencing it multiple times in different sections of the yaml file.

In addition to the YAML template shared by the answer above, I would like to share another method.
We can define YAML Parameters(type: Stage, job, step) as the template job/step/stage in the same YAML. Then we can re-use it multiple times.
Here are examples:
Stage type parameter:
parameters:
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: 
    stage: 
    jobs:
    - job: DoNothing
      pool: 
       vmimage: windows-latest
      steps:
      - powershell: Write-host "Doing nothing"

stages:
- ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }}
- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps: 
    - script: echo "1"

Job type parameter:
parameters:
- name: PreDeployJob
  type: job
  default: 
      job: 
      pool: 
       vmimage: windows-latest
      steps:
      - powershell: Write-host "Doing nothing"

stages:
- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - ${{ parameters.PreDeployJob }}
  - job: test
    steps: 
    - script: echo "1"

Step type parameter:
parameters:
- name: PreDeployStep
  type: step
  default: 
      script: echo "Doing nothing"
      displayName: PreDeployStep  
stages:
- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps: 
    - ${{ parameters.PreDeployStep }}
    - ${{ parameters.PreDeployStep }}
    - script: echo "1"

In this case, when running the Pipeline, we can modify the parameters value.
For example:

Result:


Thanks! According to the docs, it's not possible to use a task type parameter, eg to reuse UsePythonVersion@0 ? Is that correct or is there a workaround with this method? Create a jobs type parameter, and include the task under the steps?

@0vbb you can use step type. This is for reusing task.

Sorry was confused, makes sense!

In Azure DevOps, to define reusable content, logic, and parameters in YAML pipelines, you can use template.
According to Template usage reference,

Templates can help you speed up development. For example, you can have a series of the same tasks in a template and then include the template multiple times in different stages of your YAML pipeline.

Refer to the sample below for a reference.
Step reuse: There are two tasks in the template, script and bash task.
# templates/steps.yml

steps:
- script: echo "Run a script task"
  displayName: This is script task in the template
- bash: echo "Run a Bash task"
  displayName: This is bash task in the template


Main yaml file: The template is inserted twice.
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- template: templates/steps.yml
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
- template: templates/steps.yml


Result: The template is inserted twice and the tasks in it are also run twice.


Not only can you insert templates to reuse one or more steps across several jobs, you can also reuse jobs, stages, variables and parameters across the Azure pipelines.
See the following docs for the details:

Template usage reference
Template parameters.


Thanks a lot! Is it possible to have the template in the same yaml file (didn't find online), or is it only possible via a separate (template) yaml file and referencing that in the main yaml file (as you described)? Edit: Guess this is kind of adressed in the other answer.

No. Template is a separate yaml file, which you can share between pipelines/teams/projects. You can insert it in any yaml file which used to run the pipeline. If you want to reuse tasks in the same yaml, you can try the suggestion using parameter shared by @Kevin Lu-MSFT.
